# JQuery: how to append a string to the function so it will only action for a specific div id?

Tags: javascript, jquery

As per function below, if I have like multiple tables: listbox1, listbox2, listbox3, listbox4, etc and multiple buttons: btnAdd1, btnAdd2, btnRemove1, btnRemove2 etc for the corresponding 2 tables.  How do you make this dynamic enough where I do not need to hard code and create multiple functions?  How do I concatenate a string to the div id?

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnAdd1').click(function(e) {
        $('#listBox1 > option:selected').appendTo('#listBox2');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#btnAddAll1').click(function(e) {
        $('#listBox1 > option').appendTo('#listBox2');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#btnRemove1').click(function(e) {
        $('#listBox2 > option:selected').appendTo('#listBox1');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
    $('#btnRemoveAll1').click(function(e) {
        $('#listBox2 > option').appendTo('#listBox1');
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Comment: What div id? You said tables and buttons

Comment: Are the buttons dynamically generated or can you rely on those id's being there?

Comment: sorry I meant table and input id?

Comment: no, the buttons are static

Comment: Welcome to SO. Unique IDs will cause a problem as you scale up, so you should think about using classes instead. Then you will need one function. The trick is to know what button is being pressed that calls the function. Check out`$(this)` in JQ. see this Fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/5tuhyrng/1/ Once you know what triggered the function, you can traverse  the DOM using find() or next() to append your list

Comment: Thank you Cory, testing out var content = $(this).attr('id') but trying to extract listbox#?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went ahead and made an assumption about what you were trying to achieve. I think you are trying to have two lists that move options between them. This code pen uses CSS classes as well as HTML5 data attributes to assign the buttons to their appropriate lists. So rather than telling the buttons what to do, the buttons can tell the code what they want to do. Take a look at this code pen and let me know if this is what you were trying to do?

http://codepen.io/ozrevulsion/pen/xwmZXJ

**HTML**

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="col">
    <select size="15" class="from list">
      <option>Option 1</option>
      <option>Option 2</option>
      <option>Option 3</option>
      <option>Option 4</option>
      <option>Option 5</option>
      <option>Option 6</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <button class="move" data-from=".from" data-to=".to">Add</button>
    <button class="moveall" data-from=".from" data-to=".to">Add All</button>
    <button class="move" data-from=".to" data-to=".from">Remove</button>
    <button class="moveall" data-from=".to" data-to=".from">Remove All</button>
  </div>

  <div class="col">
    <select size="15"  class="to list">
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.col {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.list {
  width: 200px;
  height: 300px;
}

.move, .moveall {
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  width: 70px;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.move').click(function() {
      var from = $(this).attr('data-from');
      var to = $(this).attr('data-to');

      $(from + ' > option:selected').appendTo(to);
      $(from + ' > option:selected').remove();
    });

    $('.moveall').click(function() {
      var from = $(this).attr('data-from');
      var to = $(this).attr('data-to');

      $(from + ' > option').appendTo(to);
      $(from + ' > option').remove();
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you Zac but what happens if I have multiple from and to tables on one form?

Comment: No worries, glad to have helped. Don't forget to mark this as your answer and upvote if you like it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate a string to jquery selector by doing `$('#div_' + myString)`

Comment: how do u pass myString to the function? or multiple params / Strings

Comment: You would call `helloWorld(myString)` and you function would look like `function  helloWorld(string)`  you can add as many params as you want ie. function(a,b,c,d);

Comment: first thank you for you time.  so, <input type='image' id='btnAdd1' width="45" src="../image/add-onclick-button-png-md.png"/> I would add onClick?  I thought jquery would pick it up accordingly to the id?  $(document).ready(function(a,b,c,d) {
  $('#btnAdd').click(function(e) {
   $('#listBox1 > option:selected').appendTo('#listBox2');
   e.preventDefault();
  });

Comment: I am unable to understand the output of this as the 4 Click events you have do something different. Check out @Cory's comment.

Comment: Cory suggestion is close, working on it.  Thank you ahervin